# Comparing two dates in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, date-comparison

I have a database with a table named meeting. Meeting dates are stored in this table using the following format: `May 2nd 2011` is (for example) formatted as `5/2/2011`.

My requirement is to get the meetings between two dates (say, 4/25/2011 and 5/2/2011) and to write a query comparing a date with these two dates. Does it compare like 4/25/2011 < 4/26/2011?  How does the comparison take place?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and LINQ to SQL queries.

Comment: Do you want this done in SQL or in C# (given you're using Linq to SQL it can be done in either place).

Comment: This methods of DateTime can be used in LINQ-to-SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this

```
DateTime start = new DateTime("4/25/2011");
DateTime end = new DateTime("5/2/2011");
var result = db.Meeting.Where(d => d.MeetingDate >= start 
                 && d.MeetingDate <= end);
```

Answer (score 4):

Query style:

```
from m in db.Meetings
where m.Start => start && m.End <= end
select m;
```

Method style:

```
db.Meetings.Where(m => m.Start => start && m.End <= end);
```