# How to Check if Data Exists in Table using LinQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I can't make this to work.

variable d = takes the parse DateTime data from my form.

variable id = takes the parse Primary key from my form.

If button is click the code below executed

```
  bool flag = db.tbl_payrolls.Any(p => p.dDate == d && p.emp_id == id);
            if (flag)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("UPDATE");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INSERT");
            }
```

I test my code and if there's a record on id where date is today then it will execute the update portion else record will be inserted.

Comment: `"if there's a record on id where date is today then it will execute the update portion else record will be inserted"` - Isn't that what this code is *intending* to do?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Does `dDate` store the datetime including the time portion or only the date?

Comment: @David yes it is what I want to achieve but when I input the id with the date which does have data it should go through the Update section but it just go through the INSERT section

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it stores the date including the time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5878159/3185569

Answer (score 0):

Since your column contains also the time portion and `d` is the `DateTime` with only the date portion(as commented) you cannot filter with `p.dDate == d`.

You can use this approach:

```
DateTime fromDt = d.Date;
DateTime toDt = d.Date.AddDays(1);

bool flag = db.tbl_payrolls.Any(p => p.emp_id == id 
                                 && p.dDate >= fromDt && p.dDate < toDt);
```

Comment: Hello Mr.Tim I answer your question whether the datetime stores date only or date with time. My answer is the datetime stores date and time. Here's the sample output: 2016-09-04 00:00:00.000